# Can you correctly drop auxiliary verbs in writing?

Tags: grammar, tense, sentence-structure, auxiliary-verbs, writing

While creatively writing, I found myself dropping an auxiliary verb (I believe?) in a description. The statement went: "He seemed to be a freak of nature, his mutilated feautures artificially altered, his parchment skin impossibly white."

Is this grammatically correct or should it be, "He seemed to be a freak of nature, his mutilated feautures were artificially altered, his parchment skin was impossibly white"?

To me, the second example doesn't really read right, but I honestly don't know whether or not the first one is correct. I couldn't really find an answer online, as I wasn't sure how to word my search (though it's probably better I ask here anyway, because I can show what it is that I'm writing). So, did I write this correctly, or should I word it differently; is it okay to drop auxiliary verbs? (Oh─ and is it 'while creatively writing' or 'while creative writing', haha?)

*These may be stupid questions, but I'm a bit confused and could really use some quick help, so forgive me.* ♡

Answer (score 1):

*Was* and *were* are not auxiliaries in this context, but full verbs.

Your original text is perfectly good for writing, though it would be less common in spoken English. It contains two [small clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_clause).

Your emended version with the verbs in is also grammatical, except that it is a [run-on sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure#Run-on_sentences). The commas need to be at least semicolons, if not full stops creating three separate sentences.